# Assigning array references, incompatible types?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a custom class called ItemComponent.  Another class has an array of them called subComponents.  It's a property of the class:

```
ItemComponent *subComponents[0];
```

Initially, it is set as 0, because not all objects will have sub-components.

In the implementation, I have a method to add an ItemComponent to the property.  The item is passed in, and the assignment is coded like this (after necessary checks & switching):

```
ItemComponent *tempArray[1];
tempArray[0] = item;
subComponents = tempArray;
```

I get the error:  'incompatible types in assignment' on the last line.

They are both pointers to arrays, so what gives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, as I already wrote in a comment, I think you are sweating it too much. I guess we are talking about some game object that can have some components in it. In this case it is perfectly affordable to keep the components in an `NSArray`. The code will be easier to work with and the speed difference will be small.

If you want to sleep without worries, set up a small test that will iterate over some `NSMutableArrays` several thousand times and maybe even change some of them. Then measure the time it takes:

```
double start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
// now iterate over the arrays, send some messages, change contents
double end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
double diff = end-start; // in seconds
NSAssert(diff < 0.005, @"I’ll be damned.");
```

(The 0.005 part might be too steep depending on what you are trying to do, but I guess you get the point. 50 fps ≈ 1/50 s = 0.02 s = 20 ms for a whole frame to build. If the whole Objective-C overhead took 10 ms, you’d still have about 20 ms for the rest and keep a decent framerate of 30 fps.)

There are cases where you would want to use plain C array, for example when you’re writing a particle engine and have several thousands of items in an array that changes every loop. In that case you can simply use a pointer:

```
ItemComponent *components;
int compMax;
// …
compMax = 1000;
components = calloc(compMax, sizeof(ItemComponent));
NSAssert(components != NULL, @"Out of memory for components.");
components[0] = …;
components[1] = …;
// …
free(components);
```

I am hundred percent sure about the first point. I am not that much sure about the second, maybe there’s a safer way to do it, but I would write it this way.

Comment: A great example.  It's been a long time since I've learned/used C (from the old Turbo C days).  I wish I had the old book now!

I will try your suggestion in just using a mutable array.  Hopefully the performance impact will be minimal.

Comment: If ItemComponent is a class, `components` should be an `ItemComponent**` and the allocation should be of `sizeof(ItemComponent*)`, since objects are never directly referenced.

Comment: Chuck: Yes, thank you. I assumed that ItemComponent was a structure.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using C arrays instead of NSMutableArrays?

Comment: Yes, I'm under the impression that c arrays are much faster.  I'm using this code in a game and performance is important.

Is there a big difference performance-wise?

Comment: @Javy if performance is really sensitive, you can save a pretty good chunk of overhead by using C arrays over NSArrays (ditto for structs vs custom NSObjects)

Comment: Javy: Even in a game you should start with high-level code (NSArray) and only after a measurement switch to plain C arrays if the former is not fast enough. Most of the time you’ll find it does not make a difference and you can stick to NSArray.

Comment: Even NSMutableArrays?  I may have to go through a bunch of sub-objects that have inherited from 2-3 other classes rapidly.  I would like to achieve a 20 frame per second rate, with 30 being ideal.

Comment: The framerate usually gets capped by rendering and physics updates, not by NSArrays (mutable or not). But there is no point in discussing this – you have to measure. That’s a golden rule as far as games and performance go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if it makes a difference.

```
ItemComponent *subComponents[];
```

The way you have it defined, the subComponents array actually stores its (zero) item right there among your other class variables.  You can't reset it to point elsewhere.  In order to do that, you need to make it a pointer to a pointer to ItemComponent, instead of an array of zero length of ItemComponents.

Comment: I tried that, but then it says:

error: instance variable 'subComponents' has unknown size

I actually had it that way in the first place, and added the 0 later to appease the compiler  :)   Then I started getting the assignment errors.

Comment: Yes, I should have known.  Try this:

ItemComponent **subComponents;